# What is the origin of "can't into"?

Tags: expressions, phrase-origin

It's become popular recently to say things like "I can't into Photoshop" (I took this example from [Urban Dictionay](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Can%27t%20Into)). I wonder, what is the origin of this expression? It's obviously not grammatically correct...

Comment: How popular is ‘popular’? I’ve never heard it before, and I usually think I’m pretty good at catching Internet memes and phrases like this pretty early on. It has the sound of something based on a mistranslation (like “All your base are belong to us” and “Do not want!” in their heyday), but I have nothing to back that up with.

Comment: Please *don't* take examples from Urban Dictionary; it may or may not be a good source of slang and memes, but it is is no sense a dictionary.

Comment: If you're **into** something, it means you harbour a great interest for a particular hobby or topic. This new form using the negative seems related, *I can't **get into** photoshop* i.e. I don't understand it or I'm not interested in it.  Then you can also **fit into** something, which means a particular garment fits you well, or you can **squeeze** yourself **into** a limited space.

Comment: This usage ('an INTO clause') arguably nouns the preposition _into_. If one is prescriptive enough to apply 'you can verb any noun' rigorously ... However, _inclusion in UD_ does often seem the antonym of _inclusion in OED_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth the OED can't possibly keep up with the latest trends in teen-speak, or regional dialects. i think we should be grateful that UD exists, it provides a reliable source for dates, and for most definitions. It doesn't mean that every entry is valid, supported, or checked, but when in doubt over a weird acronym or slang I look to UD and it's been very useful, to me at least.

Comment: Fine, but I'd consider 'weird acronyms and latest trends in teen-speak' not to be suitable for a site aiming for a measure of respectability, especially when no caveat flagging such peripherality is attached. I have many fine books I wouldn't use as evidence for acceptable English usages.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Did you mean “arguably **verbs** the preposition _into_”? I can’t make sense of the sentence with _into_ interpreted as a noun.

Comment: " 'Into' is a preposition" may be easier to see this with, but if _into_ is argued to be a distinct word rather than part of a compound in what is an analogue to "that clause", it would be considered an attributive noun.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like it originated as [a running joke in an internet comic](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/polandball). It's intentionally written in broken English and mocks Poland for being technologically underdeveloped (I don't know enough about Poland, so can't vouch for that).

[image].